# Setting variable to NULL after free

Tags: c, coding-style, malloc, free, heap-memory

In my company there is a coding rule that says, after freeing any memory, reset the variable to `NULL`. For example ...

```
void some_func () 
{
    int *nPtr;

    nPtr = malloc (100);

    free (nPtr);
    nPtr = NULL;

    return;
}
```

I feel that, in cases like the code shown above, setting to `NULL` does not have any meaning. Or am I missing something?

If there is no meaning in such cases, I am going to take it up with the "quality team" to remove this coding rule. Please advice.

Comment: it is always useful to be able to check if `ptr == NULL` before doing anything with it. If you don't nullify your free'd pointers you'd get `ptr != NULL` but still unusable pointer.

Comment: [**Dangling pointers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) can lead to exploitable vulnerabilities such as [_Use-After-Free_](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/416.html).

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Setting unused pointers to NULL is a defensive style, protecting against dangling pointer bugs. If a dangling pointer is accessed after it is freed, you may read or overwrite random memory. If a null pointer is accessed, you get an immediate crash on most systems, telling you right away what the error is.

For local variables, it may be a little bit pointless if it is "obvious" that the pointer isn't accessed anymore after being freed, so this style is more appropriate for member data and global variables. Even for local variables, it may be a good approach if the function continues after the memory is released.

To complete the style, you should also initialize pointers to NULL before they get assigned a true pointer value.

Comment: I don't understand why you would "initialize pointers to NULL before they get assigned a true pointer value"?

Comment: @Paul: In the specific case, the declaration could read `int *nPtr=NULL;`. Now, I would agree that this would be redundant, with a malloc following right in the next line. However, if there is code between the declaration and the first initialization, somebody might start using the variable even though it has no value yet. If you null-initialize, you get the segfault; without, you might again read or write random memory. Likewise, if the variable later gets initialized only conditionally, later faulty accesses should give you instant crashes if you remembered to null-initialize.

Comment: @Martin v. Löwis: Ah, you're assuming old-school C where the declarations are at the top of the function? Fair enough then.

Comment: I personally think that in any none-trivial codebase getting an error for dereferencing null is as vague as getting an error for dereferencing an address you don't own. I personally never bother.

Comment: Wilhelm, the point is that with a null pointer dereference you get a determinate crash and the actual location of the problem. A bad access may or may not crash, and corrupt data or behavior in unexpected ways in unexpected places.

Comment: Actually, initializing the pointer to NULL has at least one significant drawback: it can prevent the compiler from warning you about uninitialized variables.  Unless the logic of your code actually explicitly handles that value for the pointer (i.e. if (nPtr==NULL) dosomething...) it's better to leave it as-is.

Comment: @Paul Biggar: In my class (CPEN-3710 assembly programming at UTC),
A pointer that is not explicitly initialized to a known value will be initialized to a random-garbage value. The point is that all variables should be initialized to a known value and provides both consistent and expected behavior.

Answer (score 46):

Most of the responses have focused on preventing a double free, but setting the pointer to NULL has another benefit.  Once you free a pointer, that memory is available to be reallocated by another call to malloc.  If you still have the original pointer around you might end up with a bug where you attempt to use the pointer after free and corrupt some other variable, and then your program enters an unknown state and all kinds of bad things can happen (crash if you're lucky, data corruption if you're unlucky).  If you had set the pointer to NULL after free, any attempt to read/write through that pointer later would result in a segfault, which is generally preferable to random memory corruption.

For both reasons, it can be a good idea to set the pointer to NULL after free().  It's not always necessary, though.  For example, if the pointer variable goes out of scope immediately after free(), there's not much reason to set it to NULL.

Comment: +1 This is actually a very good point. Not the reasoning about "double free" (which is completely bogus), but *this*. I'm not the fan of mechanical NULL-ing of pointers after `free`, but this actually makes sense.

Comment: If you could access a pointer after freeing it through that same pointer, it's even more likely that you'd access a pointer after freeing the object it points to through some other pointer. So this doesn't help you at all -- you still have to use some other mechanism to ensure you don't access an object through one pointer after having freed it through another one. You might as well use that method to protect in the same pointer case too.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I disagree with your comment. When I had to write a stack for an university exercise some weeks ago, I had a problem, I investigated a few hours. I accessed some already free'd memory at some point (the free was some lines too early). And sometimes it lead to very strange behaviour. If I would have set the pointer to NULL after freeing it, there would have been a "simple" segfault and I would have saved a couple of hours of work. So +1 for this answer!

Comment: @katze_sonne Even a stopped clock is right twice a day. It's much more likely that setting pointers to NULL will *hide* bugs by preventing erroneous accesses to already freed objects from segfaulting in code that checks for NULL and then silently fails to check an object it should have checked. (Perhaps setting pointers to NULL after free in specific debug builds might be helpful, or setting them to a value other than NULL that is guaranteed to segfault might make sense. But that this silliness happened to help you once is *not* an argument in its favor.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, that sounds reasonable... Thanks for your comment, I will consider this in the future! :) +1

Comment: I always assign dead pointers to NULL since their addressed memory is no longer valid. I quite like the idea of using a replace value which is set to NULL in release mode, but something like `(void*)0xdeadbeef` in debug mode so you could detect any errant usage.

Answer (score 43):

Setting a pointer to `NULL` after `free` is a dubious practice that is often popularized as a "good programming" rule on a patently false premise. It is one of those fake truths that belong to the "sounds right" category but in reality achieve absolutely nothing useful (and sometimes leads to negative consequences).

Allegedly, setting a pointer to `NULL` after `free` is supposed to prevent the dreaded "double free" problem when the same pointer value is passed to `free` more than once. In reality though, in 9 cases out of 10 the real "double free" problem occurs when *different* pointer objects holding the same pointer value are used as arguments for `free`. Needless to say, setting a pointer to `NULL` after `free` achieves absolutely nothing to prevent the problem in such cases.

Of course, it is possible to run into "double free" problem when using the same pointer object as an argument to `free`. However, in reality situations like that normally indicate a problem with the general logical structure of the code, not a mere accidental "double free". A proper way to deal with the problem in such cases is to review and rethink the structure of the code in order to avoid the situation when the same pointer is passed to `free` more than once. In such cases setting the pointer to `NULL` and considering the problem "fixed" is nothing more than an attempt to sweep the problem under the carpet. It simply won't work in general case, because the problem with the code structure will always find another way to manifest itself.

Finally, if your code is specifically designed to rely on the pointer value being `NULL` or not `NULL`, it is perfectly fine to set the pointer value to `NULL` after `free`. But as a general "good practice" rule (as in "always set your pointer to `NULL` after `free`") it is, once again, a well-known and pretty useless fake, often followed by some for purely religious, voodoo-like reasons.

Comment: Definitely. I don't remember ever causing a double-free that would be fixed by setting the pointer to NULL after freeing, but I've caused plenty that would not.

Comment: @AnT "dubious" is a bit much. It all depends on the use case. If the value of the pointer is ever used in a true/false sense, it's not only a valid practice, it's a best practice.

Comment: @Coder Completely wrong. If the value of the pointer is used in a true false sense to know whether or not it pointed to an object before the call to free, it's not only not best practice, it's *wrong*. For example: `foo* bar=getFoo(); /*more_code*/ free(bar); /*more_code*/ return bar != NULL;`. Here, setting `bar` to `NULL` after the call to `free` will cause the function to think it *never* had a bar and return the wrong value!

Comment: I don't think the primary benefit is to protect against a double free, rather it's to catch dangling pointers earlier and more reliably. For example when freeing a struct that holds resources, pointers to allocated memory, file handles, etc., as I free the contained memory pointers and close the contained files, I NULL respective members. Then if one of the resources is accessed via a dangling pointer by mistake, the program tends to fault right there, every time. Otherwise, without NULLing, the freed data might not be overwritten yet and the bug might not be easily reproducible.

Comment: I agree that well structured code should not allow the case where a pointer is accessed after being freed or the case where it's freed two times. But in the real world my code will be modified and/or mantained by someone who probably doesn't know me and doesn't have the time and/or skills to do things properly (because the deadline is always yesterday). Therefore I tend to write bulletproof functions that don't crash the system even if misused.

Answer (score 21):

This is considered good practice to avoid overwriting memory. In the above function, it is unnecessary, but oftentimes when it is done it can find application errors.

Try something like this instead:

```
#if DEBUG_VERSION
void myfree(void **ptr)
{
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
}
#else
#define myfree(p) do { void ** p_tmp = (p); free(*(p_tmp)); *(p_tmp) = NULL; } while (0)
#endif
```

The DEBUG_VERSION lets you profile frees in debugging code, but both are functionally the same.

***Edit**: Added do ... while as suggested below, thanks.*

Comment: The macro version has a subtle bug if you use it after an if statement without brackets.

Comment: What's with the (void) 0? This code do: if (x) myfree(&x); else do_foo(); becomes if (x) { free(*(&x)); *(&x) = null; } void 0; else do_foo(); The else is an error.

Comment: That macro is a perfect place for the comma operator: free(*(p)), *(p) = null. Of course the next problem is it evaluates *(p) twice. It should be { void** _pp = (p); free(*_pp); *_pp = null; } Isn't the preprocessor fun.

Comment: The macro shouldn't be in bare brackets, it should be in a `do { } while(0)` block so that `if(x) myfree(x); else dostuff();` doesn't break.

Comment: As Lutz said, the macro body `do {X} while (0)` is IMO the best way to make a macro body that "feels like and works like" a function.  Most compilers optimize out the loop anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Setting the pointer to the `free`'d memory means that any attempt to access that memory through the pointer will immediately crash, instead of causing undefined behavior. It makes it much easier to determine where things went wrong.

I can see your argument: since `nPtr` is going out of scope right after `nPtr = NULL`, there doesn't seem to be a reason to set it to `NULL`. However, in the case of a `struct` member or somewhere else where the pointer is not immediately going out of scope, it makes more sense. It's not immediately apparent whether or not that pointer will be used again by code that shouldn't be using it.

It's likely the rule is stated without making a distinction between these two cases, because it's much more difficult to automatically enforce the rule, let alone for the developers to follow it. It doesn't hurt to set pointers to `NULL` after every free, but it has the potential of pointing out big problems.

Answer (score 7):

If you reach pointer that has been free()d, it might break or not. That memory might be reallocated to another part of your program and then you get memory corruption,

If you set the pointer to NULL, then if you access it, the program always crashes with a segfault. No more ,,sometimes it works'', no more ,,crashes in unpredictible way''. It's way easier to debug.

Comment: The program does not always crash with a segfault. If the way you access the pointer means that a large enough offset is applied to it before dereferencing, then it may reach addressable memory: ((MyHugeStruct *)0)->fieldNearTheEnd. And that's even before you deal with hardware that doesn't segfault on 0 access at all. However, the program is more likely to crash with a segfault.

Answer (score 7):

the most common bug in c is the double free. Basically you do something like that

```
free(foobar);
/* lot of code */
free(foobar);
```

and it end up pretty bad, the OS try to free some already freed memory and generally it segfault. So the good practice is to set to `NULL`, so you can make test and check if you really need to free this memory

```
if(foobar != null){
  free(foobar);
}
```

also to be noted that `free(NULL)` won't do anything so you don't have to write the if statement. I am not really an OS guru but I am pretty even now most OSes would crash on double free.

That's also a main reason why all languages with garbage collection (Java, dotnet) was so proud of not having this problem and also not having to leave to developers the memory management as a whole.

Comment: You can actually just call free() without checking - free(NULL) is defined as doing nothing.

Comment: Doesn't that hide bugs? (Like freeing too much.)

Comment: if i pre-check whether the pointer has been freed already, like `if(p!=null){.....}`, is it unnecessary to set it NULL?

Comment: @Macroideal: No, you set it to `NULL` so that you _can_ pre-check it. (or just call `free()` again.)

Comment: @Macroideal. Yes, it is. free() doesn't change the pointer value. So the check will evaluate to "true" and free() will be called again for an address of already freed block.

Comment: @Macroideal: no it doesn't change a thing, you have better to set it to NULL anyway just to be safe.

Comment: @gs: Yup, it's a horrid practice. Double free is a logical error; you don't want logical errors to be hidden, you want them to blow up noisily and immediately.

Comment: thanx, I got it. i tried : `p = (char *)malloc(.....); free(p); if(p!=null) //p!=null is true, p is not null although freed { free(p); //Note: checking doesnot prevent error here } `

Comment: Clarifying on @sharptooth: `free()` _can't_ change the pointer value. To do so it would have to be `free(void **ptr)` or be a macro `#define free(x) do { __real_free(x); x = NULL; } while(0)` to do that.

Comment: @Chris Lutz  so, what the is inner details of the `free()`, what changes happened after we called the `free()`, kinda puzzled

Comment: The C runtime has a memory management system in `malloc()` and `free()` (and friends). Basically, when you call `malloc()` the system marks of a chunk of memory as "used" and then gives it to you, and when you call `free()` it marks that chunk of memory as "unused" and does whatever it wants with it (like give it to another `malloc()` call, or (more modern) start zeroing it out for security and to speed up `calloc()`). It doesn't change the _pointer itself_ but it changes the _data that was pointed to_ (or it can, anyway, which is why the pointer shouldn't be used after being freed).

Comment: @ALL: And another question, so why wasnot the system designed to set the pointer null in the function `free()`...I thnk that will more convenient

Comment: As I said, `free(void *ptr)` _cannot_ change the value of the pointer it is passed. It can change the _contents_ of the pointer, the _data stored at that address_, but not the _address itself_, or the _value of the pointer_. That would require `free(void **ptr)` (which is apparently not allowed by the standard) or a macro (which is allowed and perfectly portable but people don't like macros). Also, C isn't about convenience, it's about giving programmers as much control as they want. If they don't want the added overhead of setting pointers to `NULL`, it shouldn't be forced on them.

Comment: There are few things in the world that give away the lack of professionalism on part of the C code author. But they include "checking the pointer for NULL before calling `free`" (along with such things as "casting the result of memory allocation functions" or "thoughtless using of type names with `sizeof`").

Answer (score 6):

The idea behind this, is to stop accidental reuse of the freed pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Recently I come across the same question after I was looking for the answer. I reached this conclusion:

It is best practice, and one must follow this to make it portable on all (embedded) systems.

`free()` is a library function, which varies as one changes the platform, so you should not expect that after passing pointer to this function and after freeing memory, this pointer will be set to NULL. This may not be the case for some library implemented for the platform.

so always go for

```
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;
```

Answer (score 5):

This (can) actually be important. Although you free the memory, a later part of the program could allocate something new that happens to land in the space. Your old pointer would now point to a valid chunk of memory. It is then possible that someone would use the pointer, resulting in invalid program state.

If you NULL out the pointer, then any attempt to use it is going to dereference 0x0 and crash right there, which is easy to debug. Random pointers pointing to random memory is hard to debug. It's obviously not necessary but then that's why it's in a best practices document.

Comment: On Windows, at least, debug builds will set the memory to 0xdddddddd so when you use a pointer to deleted memory you know right away.  There should be similar mechanisms on all platforms.

Comment: jeffamaphone, deleted memory block might have get reallocated and assigned to *another* object by the time you use the pointer again.

Answer (score 5):

From the ANSI C standard:

```
void free(void *ptr);
```

> The free function causes the space
>   pointed to by ptr to be deallocated,
>   that is, made available for further
>   allocation.  If ptr is a null pointer,
>   no action occurs.  Otherwise, if the
>   argument does not match a pointer
>   earlier returned by the calloc ,
>   malloc , or realloc function, or if
>   the space has been deallocated by a
>   call to free or realloc , the behavior
>   is undefined.

"the undefined behavior" is almost always a program crash. So as to avoid this it is safe to reset the pointer to NULL. free() itself cannot do this as it is passed only a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer. You can also write a safer version of free() that NULLs the pointer:

```
void safe_free(void** ptr)
{
  free(*ptr);
  *ptr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: @DrPizza - An error (in my opinion) is something that causes your program not to work as it's supposed to. If a hidden double free breaks your program, it's an error. If it works exactly how it was intended to, it's not an error.

Comment: @DrPizza: I've just found an argument why one should set it to `NULL` to avoid masking errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025589/setting-variable-to-null-after-free It seems like in either case some errors get hidden.

Comment: Be aware that a void pointer-to-pointer has its problems: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html

Comment: @Secure - Interesting. It seems that the best solution (IMHO) is the macro approach based on this FAQ.

Comment: @Chris, no, the best approach is code structure. Don't throw random mallocs and frees all over your codebase, keep related things together. The "module" that allocates a resource (memory, file, ...) is responsible for freeing it and has to provide a function for doing so that keeps care for the pointers, too. For any specific resource, you then have exactly one place where it is allocated and one place where it is released, both close together.

Comment: @Secure - Well, yeah, the best solution is always writing your program correctly in the first place, but that can't always happen. That's why people practice defensive coding habits.

Comment: @Chris, actually I'm talking about DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself, one of the most defensive coding habits I've learned. It can always be done, maybe except for the quick one-time-run hack scripts that have to be finished yesterday, but there you won't care for the pointers, too... and except when you have to maintain a legacy codebase... However, DRY is strongly related with modularization and code reuse and will nearly always effectively save you time and nerves in the long run.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Hogwash. If you write code that frees the same pointer twice, your program has a logical error in it. Masking that logical error by making it not crash doesn't mean that the program is correct: it's still doing something nonsensical. There is no scenario in which writing a double free is justified.

Answer (score 4):

I find this to be little help as in my experience when people access a freed memory allocation it's almost always because they have another pointer to it somewhere. And then it conflicts with another personal coding standard which is "Avoid useless clutter", so I don't do it as I think it rarely helps and makes the code slightly less readable.

However - I won't set the variable to null if the pointer isn't supposed to be used again, but often the higher level design gives me a reason to set it to null anyway. For example if the pointer is a member of a class and I've deleted what it points to then the "contract" if you like of the class is that that member will point to something valid at any time so it must be set to null for that reason. A small distinction but I think an important one.

In c++ it's important to always be thinking who *owns* this data when you allocate some memory (unless you are using smart pointers but even then some thought is required). And this process tends to lead to pointers generally being a member of some class and generally you want a class to be in a valid state at all times, and the easiest way to do that is to set the member variable to NULL to indicate it points to nothing now.

A common pattern is to set all the member pointers to NULL in the constructor and have the destructor call delete on any pointers to data that your design says that class *owns*. Clearly in this case you have to set the pointer to NULL when you delete something to indicate that you don't own any data before.

So to summarise, yes i often set the pointer to NULL after deleting something, but it's as part of a larger design and thoughts on who owns the data rather than due to blindly following a coding standard rule. I wouldn't do so in your example as I think there is no benefit to doing so and it adds "clutter" which in my experience is just as responsible for bugs and bad code as this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

It is always advisable to declare a pointer variable with **NULL** such as,

```
int *ptr = NULL;
```

Let's say, **ptr** is pointing to **0x1000** memory address.
After using `free(ptr)`, it's always advisable to nullify the pointer variable by declaring again to **NULL**.
e.g.:

```
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;
```

If not re-declared to **NULL**, the pointer variable still keeps on pointing to the same address (**0x1000**), this pointer variable is called a **dangling pointer**.
If you define another pointer variable (let's say, **q**) and dynamically allocate address to the new pointer, there is a chance of taking the same address (**0x1000**) by new pointer variable. If in case, you use the same pointer (**ptr**) and update the value at the address pointed by the same pointer (**ptr**), then the program will end up writing a value to the place where **q** is pointing (since **p** and **q** are pointing to the same address (**0x1000**)).

e.g.

```
*ptr = 20; //Points to 0x1000
free(ptr);
int *q = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); //Points to 0x1000
*ptr = 30; //Since ptr and q are pointing to the same address, so the value of the address to which q is pointing would also change.
```

Answer (score 3):

This rule is useful when you're trying to avoid the following scenarios:

1) You have a really long function with complicated logic and memory management and you don't want to accidentally reuse the pointer to deleted memory later in the function.

2) The pointer is a member variable of a class that has fairly complex behavior and you don't want to accidentally reuse the pointer to deleted memory in other functions.

In your scenario, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but if the function were to get longer, it might matter.

You may argue that setting it to NULL may actually mask logic errors later on, or in the case where you assume it is valid, you still crash on NULL, so it doesn't matter.

In general, I would advise you to set it to NULL when you think it is a good idea, and not bother when you think it isn't worth it.  Focus instead on writing short functions and well designed classes.

Answer (score 3):

This might be more an argument to initialize all pointers to NULL, but something like this can be a very sneaky bug:

```
void other_func() {
  int *p; // forgot to initialize
  // some unrelated mallocs and stuff
  // ...
  if (p) {
    *p = 1; // hm...
  }
}

void caller() {
  some_func();
  other_func();
}
```

`p` ends up in the same place on the stack as the former `nPtr`, so it might still contain a seemingly valid pointer. Assigning to `*p` might overwrite all kinds of unrelated things and lead to ugly bugs. Especially if the compiler initializes local variables with zero in debug mode but doesn't once optimizations are turned on. So the debug builds don't show any signs of the bug while release builds blow up randomly...

Answer (score 3):

Set the pointer that has just been freed to NULL is not mandatory but a good practice. In this way , you can avoid 1) using a freed pointed 2)free it towice

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons:

### Avoid crashes when double-freeing

*Written by [RageZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169442/ragez) in a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879168/why-set-a-pointer-to-null-after-calling-free-in-c/1879173#1879173).*

> The most common bug in c is the double
>   free. Basically you do something like
>   that
>
> ```
> free(foobar);
> /* lot of code */
> free(foobar);
> ```
>
> and it end up pretty bad, the OS try
>   to free some already freed memory and
>   generally it segfault. So the good
>   practice is to set to `NULL`, so you
>   can make test and check if you really
>   need to free this memory
>
> ```
> if(foobar != NULL){
>   free(foobar);
> }
> ```
>
> also to be noted that `free(NULL)`
>   won't do anything so you don't have to
>   write the if statement. I am not
>   really an OS guru but I am pretty even
>   now most OSes would crash on double
>   free.
>
> That's also a main reason why all
>   languages with garbage collection
>   (Java, dotnet) was so proud of not
>   having this problem and also not
>   having to leave to developer the
>   memory management as a whole.

### Avoid using already freed pointers

*Written by [Martin v. Löwis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33006/martin-v-lowis) in a [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025589/setting-variable-to-null-after-free/1025604#1025604).*

> Setting unused pointers to NULL is a
>   defensive style, protecting against
>   dangling pointer bugs. If a dangling
>   pointer is accessed after it is freed,
>   you may read or overwrite random
>   memory. If a null pointer is accessed,
>   you get an immediate crash on most
>   systems, telling you right away what
>   the error is.
>
> For local variables, it may be a
>   little bit pointless if it is
>   "obvious" that the pointer isn't
>   accessed anymore after being freed, so
>   this style is more appropriate for
>   member data and global variables. Even
>   for local variables, it may be a good
>   approach if the function continues
>   after the memory is released.
>
> To complete the style, you should also
>   initialize pointers to NULL before
>   they get assigned a true pointer
>   value.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what other have said, one good method of pointer usage is to always check whether it is a valid pointer or not. Something like:

```
if(ptr)
   ptr->CallSomeMethod();
```

Explicitly marking the pointer as NULL after freeing it allows for this kind of usage in C/C++.

Comment: In many cases, where a NULL pointer makes no sense, it would be preferable to write an assertion instead.

Answer (score 2):

Settings a pointer to NULL is to protect agains so-called double-free - a situation when free() is called more than once for the same address without reallocating the block at that address.

Double-free leads to undefined behaviour - usually heap corruption or immediately crashing the program. Calling free() for a NULL pointer does nothing and is therefore guaranteed to be safe.

So the best practice unless you now for sure that the pointer leaves scope immediately or very soon after free() is to set that pointer to NULL so that even if free() is called again it is now called for a NULL pointer and undefined behaviour is evaded.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that if you try to dereference the no-longer-valid pointer after freeing it, you want to fail hard (segfault) rather than silently and mysteriously.

But... be careful. Not all systems cause a segfault if you dereference NULL. On (at least some versions of) AIX, *(int *)0 == 0, and Solaris has optional compatibility with this AIX "feature."

Answer (score 2):

To the original question: 
Setting the pointer to NULL directly after freeing the contents is a complete waste of time, provided the code meets all requirements, is fully debugged and will never be modified again. On the other hand, defensively NULLing a pointer that has been freed can be quite useful when someone thoughtlessly adds a new block of code beneath the free(), when the design of the original module isn't correct, and in the case of it-compiles-but-doesn't-do-what-I-want bugs.


In any system, there is an unobtainable goal of making it easiest to the right thing, and the irreducible cost of inaccurate measurements. In C we're offered a set of very sharp, very strong tools, which can create many things in the hands of a skilled worker, and inflict all sorts of metaphoric injuries when handled improperly. Some are hard to understand or use correctly. And people, being naturally risk averse, do irrational things like checking a pointer for NULL value before calling free with it…


The measurement problem is that whenever you attempt to divide good from less good, the more complex the case, the more likely you get an ambiguous measurement. If the goal is do keep only good practices, then some ambiguous ones get tossed out with the actually not good. IF your goal is to eliminate the not good, then the ambiguities may stay with the good. The two goals, keep only good or eliminate clearly bad, would seem to be diametrically opposed, but there is usually a third group that's neither one nor the other, some of both. 


Before you make a case with the quality department, try looking through the bug data base to see how often, if ever, invalid pointer values caused problems that had to be written down. If you want to make real difference, identify the most common problem in your production code and propose three ways to prevent it

Comment: Good answer. I'd like to add one thing. Reviewing the bug database is good to do for a variety of reasons. But in the context of the original question, keep in mind it would be hard to know how many invalid pointer problems were prevented, or at least caught so early as to not have made it into the bug database. Bug history provides better evidence for adding coding rules.

Answer (score 1):

As you have a quality assurance team in place, let me add a minor point about QA. Some automated QA tools for C will flag assignments to freed pointers as "useless assignment to `ptr`". For example PC-lint/FlexeLint from Gimpel Software says
`tst.c  8  Warning 438: Last value assigned to variable 'nPtr' (defined at line 5) not used`

There are ways to selectively suppress messages, so you can still satisfy both QA requirements, should your team decide so.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: You do not want to accidentally (by mistake) access the address that you have freed. Because, when you free the address, you allow that address in the heap to be allocated to some other application.

However, if you do not set the pointer to NULL, and by mistake try to de-reference the pointer, or change the value of that address; YOU CAN STILL DO IT. BUT NOT SOMETHING THAT YOU WOULD LOGICALLY WANT TO DO.

Why can I still access the memory location that I have freed? Because: You may have free the memory, but the pointer variable still had information about the heap memory address. So, as a defensive strategy, please set it to NULL.