# Why should we nullify pointer after freeing memory by free()?

Tags: c, pointers, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should one really set pointers to `NULL` after freeing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879550/should-one-really-set-pointers-to-null-after-freeing-them)

I have allocated dynamic memory to pointer using malloc and calloc. After using this pointer, I should free the memory so that block can be returned to OS(its fine). Now My question is that after freeing the block, why should I do something like that:

```
pointer = NULL;
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should one really set pointers to `NULL` after freeing them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879550/should-one-really-set-pointers-to-null-after-freeing-them). Also see: [Setting variable to NULL after free](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025589/setting-variable-to-null-after-free) and [Is it always a good practice to set pointers to NULL after free()-ing them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365772/is-it-always-a-good-practice-to-set-pointers-to-null-after-free-ing-them), among others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So that we don't leave **dangling pointers** behind. Without nulling out unused pointers, you have no way to detect later whether the pointer can be safely dereferenced or freed. And **attempting to dereference or free a dangling pointer results in undefined behaviour** ( = crash).

Comment: It crashes only if you're lucky. The worst part is that program usually survives, but it becames very difficult to find the bug in code.

Comment: @ruslik, indeed. Although eventually it will (almost always) crash nonetheless. I just wanted to give a simple explanation for the OP :-)

Answer (score 3):

Because if you try to `free()` it again `Undefined Behaviour` will occur.

Also, note that after `free`-ing, the memory is reclaimed by the program. not the OS. The memory is reclaimed by the OS, after the execution of the program has ended.

Answer (score 2):

If the pointer variable remains in scope you can't later find whether it stores a valid address or not and if you try to use that pointer you run into undefined behavior.

Setting a pointer to null after `free()` is a protection measure. You don't need this if you know that the pointer will get out of scope soon after `free()`:

```
if( ... ) {
    void* ptr;
    ptr = malloc( ... );
    //use the buffer;
    free( ptr );
    ptr = 0; //not actually needed
}
```

but at the same time most compilers will see that in such case setting a pointer to null has no observable effect and optimize that code away.

Answer (score 1):

It is better because :

First, it makes your code simpler. When you manage memory, you do `malloc` and `free` a lot of time. If you set it to NULL you can do things like :

```
int *pMyInteger;

/* in init code */

pMyInteger = (int *) malloc(42);

/* use pMyInteger */

free(pMyInteger);
pMyInteger = NULL;

/* somewhere else you have to change the size */

free(pMyInteger);
pMyInteger = (int *) malloc(42 * 10000);
```

It's really easier, no ?

Second, it is easier too to spot a NULL (0) pointer in the debugger than a dangled one. It easy to guess that there is a pointer management problem when you see `0x0` in the debugger.When you see `0xbac765`, it's harder :)

my2c