# Differences among several ways of writing conditions with pointers

Tags: c++

I am wondering if anyone can please summarize the differences among the following ways of writing a conditional statement involving a pointer:

```
if(p)
if(p != 0)
if(p != NULL)
```

I am often confused at the following situations (there must be more, please supplement with yours) when to use which:

```
static char *p1;
char *p2 = new char();
const char *p3 = "hello"; /*then I repeatedly do p3++*/
char *p4 = 0;
char *p5 = NULL;
```

**Edit**

Also, I'd like to know, for `char *p`, do we have `while(*p)` or `while(*p!=0)`, possibly equivalent to `while(p)` or `while(p!=0)` or `while(p!=NULL)` or `while(*p!='\0')` (or any other?) after some `p++` inside the while loop?

Comment: The OP is using `new`, so it's [tag:C++].

Comment: @Tomalak: does it matter for the purpose of this question since the two languages are essentially the same in these scenarios? I could have used `malloc` instead of new in `p2`.

Comment: @muntoo: I was hoping that the OP could figure that out for us. Thanks for spoonfeeding, though.

Comment: @QiangLi: In the context of teaching, yes, it matters greatly.

Comment: For new questions, start a new question. Do not edit in new questions after answers have appeared.

Comment: You have a lot of questions... Did you try googling them?

Comment: @muntoo: yes, but I did not find some definite answers. that is why I posted my q's here. Just as a summary. Not that I did not know any answer to these.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(p)
```

In this context `p` is converted to `bool` which is effectively the same as `p != 0`.

```
if(p!=0)
```

This is the explicit way to check for a null pointer, is the same as the previous one.

```
if(p != NULL)
```

The difference with this one is that `NULL` is a macro; in C is defined as `(void*)0` while in C++ is defined as `0`. Again, its the same check than the first two expressions.

Basically, they all do the same thing (with the exception of the `NULL` macro not being defined or being redefined to something else). I tend to use `p != 0` because its the same as `p` but its stated explicitly. The version using `NULL` requires including `stddef` or `cstddef` which is usually not a problem.

In C++11 there is a new way to check for null pointers: `nullptr` which is a new keyword. It would be the ideal choice when available, since it states clearly that `p` is a pointer:

```
if( p != nullptr )
```

Comment: when you said "Basically, they all do the same thing.", do you mean they are the same in all situations?

Comment: @QiangLi: With the exception of the `NULL` macro not being defined, or being redefined to something else (nasty!), then yes the are the same in all situations for which `p` is a pointer.

Comment: @Qiang Li: Some of your expressions check whether the pointer is null, some check whether the char it points to is 0. Try to figure out which is which.

Answer (score -1):

These are all ways of checking if `p` is not `0`; they do the same thing:

```
if(p)            // Short and simple.
if(p != 0)       // Easier to understand.
if(p != NULL)    // POINTERS ONLY.
```

In C++11, you can use this 'safer' way to [check if the pointer is `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025589/setting-variable-to-null-after-free/1025604#1025604):

```
if(p != nullptr)
```

---

When you want to make a 'dynamically allocated' array of `char`s, you do:

```
char *p2 = new char[4];
strcpy(p2, "abc");

// Don't forget to delete!
delete[] p2;
```

A better alternative is to use the safer C++:

```
std::array<char, 256> p2 = {'b', 'b', 'c', 0};
p2[0] = 'a'; // "abc"
```

Or:

```
std::string p2 = "bbc";
p2 = "abc";
p2[0] = 'c'; // "cbc"
```

---

This sets `p3` to the string `"hello"`:

```
const char *p3 = "hello";
```

This increases the location `p3` points to in memory:

```
// *p3 = 'h';

p3++;
// *p3 = 'e';

p3++;
// *p3 = 'l';

p3++;
// *p3 = 'l';
```

---

To understand why you do:

```
char *p4 = 0;
char *p5 = NULL;
```

Check out this question: [Setting variable to NULL after free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025589/setting-variable-to-null-after-free/1025604#1025604)

---

I wouldn't really ever use `static char*`s in C++, but here's a stupid example:

```
void sc(char *first = NULL)
{
    static char *p = NULL;

    if(p == NULL)
        p = &first;

    // p will never change (even when sc() ends) unless you set it to NULL again:
    // p = NULL;
}

char initial_value;
sc(&initial_value);
sc();
sc();
// ...
```

Comment: Tempted to vote this answer down (in fact, I did after the latest edit). The first version was not an answer to the actual question, and a later version stated the same as what was already covered in the other answers. On top of that, the link for "check if the pointer is NULL" points to "Should one really set pointers to `NULL` after freeing them?" which is unrelated the checking for NULL. A third version added text about allocating arrays, which is totally unrelated the question at all.

Comment: @Sjoerd I was addressing "*I am often confused at the following situations (there must be more, please supplement with yours) when to use which: ...*"