# Allocating more than needed

Tags: c

I have written a code that allocated a buffer that get assigned the file's contents. Running the code through valgrind gives me this

total heap usage: 9 allocs, 7 frees, 10,905 bytes allocated

If I am not mistaken the code allocates only 3 times, and I am deal locating when needed.

```
void read_from_file (const char* filename, size_t length, char* buffer)
{
  /* put your code here */
  FILE* fOpen;

  buffer = (char*)malloc(length+1);
  fOpen = fopen(filename, "r");

  if(!buffer) // --- Failed to allocate
    printf("Failed to allocate...\n");

  else if(!fOpen){ // --- Failed to open file
    free(buffer);
    fprintf(stdout, "Failed to read %s\n", filename);
    buffer = NULL;
  }

  else if(fgets(buffer, length+1, fOpen)!=NULL){ // Buffer has been copied
    fprintf(stdout, "buff is: %s\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
  }
  else{ // --- Failed to copy correctly
    fprintf(stdout, "Failed to copy %s file...\n", filename);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
  }
}

void main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char* buff = NULL;

  read_from_file("test1.txt",10,buff);
  read_from_file("test2.txt",10,buff);
  read_from_file("test3.txt",10,buff);

}
```

Comment: Library functions can also do allocations. Namely `fopen`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @kaylum is there any way I can ensure that I deallocate the allocated buffers?

Comment: @Rob My question is why are there allocated variables that are not being deallocated? and is my deallocation done correctly?

Comment: What does Valgrind say in the LEAK SUMMARY?

Comment: @DavidBowling LEAK SUMMARY:
==8426==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8426==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8426==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8426==    still reachable: 1,104 bytes in 2 blocks
==8426==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

Comment: You should remove the needless `buffer = NULL;` statements. They make the code verbose and much harder to follow. Every time I see them, I look for where that matters later in the code, find that it doesn't, and wonder why you sent me on a wild goose chase.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025589/setting-variable-to-null-after-free, 2009 but I think it's still usable, David

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think that setting pointers to NULL after you are done with them is good practice. (In fact it's required coding style at my current employer.)

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino Yes, that shows some of the reasons it's awful practice. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1879469/721269) is particularly good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you have no memory leaks, but you have not closed the files that you opened. This is the source of the "still reachable" blocks in the Valgrind report. Just `fclose(fOpen)` before returning from the `read_from_file()` function.

Also, the return type of `main()` is `int`, not `void`. Here is your updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_from_file (const char* filename, size_t length, char* buffer)
{
  /* put your code here */
  FILE* fOpen;

  buffer = malloc(length+1);
  fOpen = fopen(filename, "r");

  if(!buffer) // --- Failed to allocate
    printf("Failed to allocate...\n");

  else if(!fOpen){ // --- Failed to open file
    free(buffer);
    fprintf(stdout, "Failed to read %s\n", filename);
    buffer = NULL;
  }

  else if(fgets(buffer, length+1, fOpen)!=NULL){ // Buffer has been copied
    fprintf(stdout, "buff is: %s\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
  }
  else{ // --- Failed to copy correctly
    fprintf(stdout, "Failed to copy %s file...\n", filename);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
  }

  if (fclose(fOpen) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to close file");
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  char* buff = NULL;

  read_from_file("test1.txt",10,buff);
  read_from_file("test2.txt",10,buff);
  read_from_file("test3.txt",10,buff);

  return 0;
}
```

And the output from Valgrind:

```
==3564== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3564==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3564==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 1,737 bytes allocated
==3564== 
==3564== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3564== 
==3564== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3564== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: ~~I added fclose(fOpen) before leaving read_from_file(), now I am getting seg fault.~~
Edit: I forgot the if-statement