# Where to free In C Code

Tags: c, arrays, copy, malloc

I have a working C code. It connnects 2 char arrays and prints the solution out. 
 But I have a dynamic memory management here (malloc) and have to free it now. 
Can someone tell me where to free and why?

```
char * stringcat(const char * str1, const char * str2) {
    int length_1 = strlength(str1);
    int length_2 = strlength(str2);
    int length = length_1 + length_2 + 1;

    char * newstr = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);

    for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char charToCopy = '\0';
        if(i < length_1)
        {
            charToCopy = *(str1 + i);
        } else if(i < (length_1 + length_2)) {
            charToCopy = *(str2 + i - length_1);
        }

        *(newstr + i) = charToCopy;
    }

    return newstr;
}


int strlength(char *c) {
    int count = 0;
    while(*(c + count) != '\0') {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}


int main() {

    char surname[] = "Simon";
    char lastname[] = "Arndt";

    printf("%s\n", stringcat(surname, lastname));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `free` memory when you no longer need it .. simple as that

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [Ask].  There are probably existing answers to this question in these search results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5Dwhere+to+free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you should free the memory at the point where you don't need it any more. For that you should store the pointer somewhere.

```
int main() {
    char surname[] = "Simon";
    char lastname[] = "Arndt";
    char *res;

    res = stringcat(surname, lastname); // first store it
    if(res == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error");
        return 1;
    }

    // then print it
    puts(res); // equivalent to printf("%s\n", res);


    free(res);

    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget that C-Strings are `\0`-terminated, that means that when you
dynamically allocate memory for a string, you should allocate at least
`strlen(string) + 1`:

```
char * newstr = malloc(length + 1);

if(newstr == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

In case of strings you don't need the `sizeof(char)` because it is always one.

For other types, avoid using `sizeof(<type>)`, it's easy to make mistakes.
Instead do it like this:

```
int *arr = malloc(10 * sizeof *arr);
```

The `sizeof *arr` will always return the correct number of bytes.

**edit**

You should always check for that `malloc` doesn't return `NULL`. Sure, for a
simple program like this, you can skip it. But in a larger project, you
definitely should check that.

Comment: thanks. so you recomment to null res at the end? "res = NULL;"

Comment: @jwdonahue technically there is no guarantee that size of pointers should the same, but in practice they are. `sizeof *ptr` however will return the correct size. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-the-same-size-in-one-platform-for-all-data-types

Comment: @SimonArndt For me, it depends. There are good reasons for doing it, but in your example there is no point, because your program ends at that point anyway. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025604/1480131

Comment: @jwdonahue I didn't say that. If `arr` is for example a simple pointer, then `sizeof arr != sizeof *arr` (there might be types where this is true, but not in general).

Comment: @Pablo, brain fart. I deleted my comment the same time you posted your response.  My lesdyxia is messing with my head today.

Comment: While not an issue in the case, always make sure you check for other return statements in the code that have might otherwise exited without freeing any malloc'ed memory.  Often that "never-mind I'm leaving early," return statement can have you bleeding heap memory.

Answer (score 2):

You leak memory because you don't assign the result of `stringcat` to a `char *`. Do so. And then `free` that after you `print`. Or (in a trivial program such as presented here) don't worry about it, and let `main` exiting cause it for you.

```
char *name = stringcat(surname, lastname);
printf("%s\n", name);
free(name);
```

Comment: don't worry about free? xdd

Comment: But how to free after print?

Comment: Like that: free(stringcat(surname, lastname)); ?

Comment: @mariusz_latarnik01 in a simple program like the OP's program there is no harm in forgetting the `free`, because the OS will free any memory left when the process is gone. I do however believes that that's bad style. For larger projects you should free the memory when you don't need it.

Comment: @SimonArndt If you call it twice, then you allocate memory twice. If you `free` it as you propose there then you allocate two and free one. That's the same memory leak (plus a pointless allocation and free).

Comment: @SimonArndt read our answers, we've both told you how to deal with it.